# Error in angular, VM1973 angular.js:11655 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'NewsPostListCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular, just trying my hand on it. I got stuck with the issue where angular is not able to find my controller. here is my link to plunkr. http://plnkr.co/edit/D1S0UBha7Dil6gLQNx0w?p=preview. looking for help.

Code from script.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var newsPostsModule = angular.module("newspostmodule", []);
}());
```

code from ctrl.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("newspostmodule").controller("NewsPostListCtrl", NewsPostListCtrl);

    function NewsPostListCtrl() {
        var newsPostm = this;
        newsPostm.newsposts = [
        {
            "heading": "header",
            "author": "author",
            "postDate": "postDate",
            "comment": "comment",
            "like": 2
        },
        {
            "heading": "header1",
            "author": "author1",
            "postDate": "postDate1",
            "comment": "comment1",
            "like": 10
        }]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing:

```
function NewsPostListCtrl() { ....
```

You should try considering `var newPostListCtrl = function () { ...` and register it to the line above here:

```
angular.module("newspostmodule").controller("NewsPostListCtrl", newsPostListCtrl);
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks it worked.. Could you please explain why its was not working with my code without using the variable?

Comment: Ohh.. I got the issue. I missed to execute the function by '()' at the end.